# why is TLS/SSL necessary?

Tags: php, openssl, ssl

I know everyone uses TLS/SSL as transport layer security on the web.

What would prevent me from generating let's say keypair manually, encrypting data client-side (using JS for example) with that public key and submitting that data to my server with http's GET/POST request?

I mean - I can just use JS library to encrypt some form data with that public key - right?

Only person who has private key can decrypt it - right? And private key would be kept on the server of course. No key warning will pop up - since transmission is a regular http request. So why I need TLS?

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel when there are methods already in use that have proven them with time and wide industry peer review. Trying to make your own system will be tedious and may actually open up your system to attack if not properly implemented. Just my opinion. =o)

Comment: @cryptic While your advice is good in general, the specific case of using JavaScript (that was presumably sent over an unencrypted channel) to encrypt/decrypt data is not only vulnerable to implementation mistakes, it isn't even securable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's give an example of how this could go wrong. Let's say that what you're trying to encrypt is some form data and send it to the server. The server sends it's public key to the client to encrypt with. The client in JavaScript encrypts this data and sends it to the server. Assuming that's what happened you'd be okay.

Now let's explore how this could go wrong. With the status of switching and the like these days it is fairly hard to sniff someone else's packets without access to the hardware. Therefore, most of the cases you are trying to avoid also allow the attacker to present a man in the middle attack. In this case the attacker could provide the client with whatever JavaScript they pleased. A clandestine way of stealing data would be to provide JavaScript that does everything that the original JavaScript does, and the also sends the unencrypted data to another server.

This can happen in a similar fashion for data from the server being sent to the client.

P.S. If your problem is the lack of a CA signed cert, I would suggest getting a free one from http://www.startssl.com/

Comment: Ahh. yes. makes sense - JS file that does encryption can still be substituted for malicious one. makes sense... And right now the piece of code that does encryption is built into browser- right?

Comment: The TLS/SSL code is built into the browser, yes. If your trouble is the lack of a cert, I would suggest getting a free one here: http://www.startssl.com/ (I'll add it to the answer as well).

Answer (score 5):

How do you trust that the Javascript delivered to the browser is the Javascript that will encrypt with the correct key?

Think about it for a second, and realize that security best practices are very subtle and nuanced and simply slapping encryption on top is not a solution.

Also, if you're dealing with the "key popup", you've broken one leg of the TLS trust model (the trusted certificate authority) by using an unsigned server certificate.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.  You can do that, and you'll have utilized strong cryptography, which is in fact one of the underlying components of SSL/TLS.

One of the issues is that computing that for every piece of data is computationally expensive.  You also need to have cross compatible libraries on the client and server that handle the encryption/decryption process.

However, you will have lost any transparency in your web application because you now have to perform this encryption process on every piece of data you need to keep secret.

TLS is session oriented, so this is not an apples to apples comparison.  What TLS is doing is setting up an encrypted session that is transparent to the client and server.  It's making an encrypted pipe and allowing data to flow through it.  It also has baked in concepts of "Trust" and identity, so that a client can have some indication that the information they are sending is going to the person they think it is.

What you are describing is taking pieces of data, encrypting them, then sending the encrypted version, and requiring decryption on the other side prior to use.  Your scheme can and will work if you want to go through the pain of getting it setup, but what have you gained?  Furthermore, since your scheme will have none of the things that TLS has in preventing man in the middle attacks, it's susceptible to those problems in a number of ways -- from someone injecting their own library and key into the client so that your app starts sending data to them instead of you, or that they get between you and the client, and send data to you that your server believes is coming directly from them and is instead coming from the attacker.

Answer (score 1):

Digital certificates include the public key of the subject, digitally signed by the CA using their private key. Your browser contains certificates identifying their public keys (signed, in the case of root certificates, with the same private key) and this allows your browser, assuming it trusts the pre-installed CA certificates, to verify your identity. When you access a server, the server-side certificate is used to transmit the server's public key to your browser, which it then uses to encrypt the initial exchange of credentials. When client-side certificates are required, similar considerations allow the server to identify you.

There's nothing to stop you using your public key in a JS library to encrypt data, but how is the server supposed to decrypt it? Passing it your private key negates the purpose of the private key, which is to ensure that only you can decrypt information encrypted with your public key. So the correct way to proceed would be to encrypt with your private key, but then anyone who has your pubic key can decrypt it (this technique is usually used for digital signature).

Really you should use the server's public key to encrypt your transmission, and let it use its private key to decrypt it. The whole business of secure key exchange is very subtle, and  there are many examples (from IBM downwards) of companies and people developing their own encryption systems, relying on privacy of the algorithm. They have always proved to be relatively easy to break. Best not to design your own system until you have a little more security experience ...

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes no sense.

If you generate a key pair and encrypt with the public key, only you can decrypt that message. So sending it to someone else is futile. You could encrypt with the server's public key, but then you have the problem of establishing exactly what that is, securely.

And then the server has no way to encrypt data back to you, unless it uses your public key, in which case it has the same problem of authenticating your identity that you already had as the client.

TLS/SSL solves those problems, and a few others you haven't thought of yet.